# Set default schema = ALGO en oracle usando Spring Boot y Spring JDBC

Tags: java, oracle, spring, spring-boot

Yo estoy ahora trabajando con Oracle y Spring JDBC, pero no deseo usar el schema en mis sentencias sql:

Ejemplo: `Select * from SCHEMA.table`

¿Hay alguna forma de establecer el schema por defecto en application.properties o application.yml?

Ojo estoy usando spring jdbc, no hibernate. Hibernate sí tiene para establecer esa propiedad. ¿Pero qué pasa cuando usas sentencias sql?

Answer (score 1):

Si fuera `postgreSQL` o `mySQL` podrías poner el schema por defecto directamente en la url de jbdc, algo así:

```
jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydatabase?searchpath=myschema
```

Pero no para oracle, `:(` por lo que hay que buscar algun *workaround*, tienes varias opciones:

- Puedes decirle a tu bbdd que ponga un schema por defecto una vez la sesión esté iniciada:

  ```
  ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA = TU_SCHEMA
  ```
- También puedes crear sinonimos en la bbdd de este modo, pero si tienes muchas tablas puede ser engorroso y complicado de mantener.

  ```
  create synonym mi_tabla for TU_SCHEMA.tu_tabla;

  select * from tu_tabla;
  ```
- Si nada de esto te funciona, [**aqui**](https://community.oracle.com/thread/1038211?start=5&tstart=6) puedes encontrar un snippet que cambia manualmente el schema.

**FUENTES:** [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4168689/is-it-possible-to-specify-schema-when-connecting-to-postgres-with-jdbc), [2](https://community.oracle.com/thread/1038211?start=0&tstart=0), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2353594/default-schema-in-oracle-connection-url).

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que veo el usuario que usas para conectarte a la DB no es el mismo usuario dueño de las tablas.  Entonces para solucionar el problema el DBA o quien está a cargo de la DB, debe crear los sinónimos en las tablas que usas al usuario que ocupas.
con esto podras ocupar las tablas sin su owner.

Answer (score 0):

En Oracle, cada usuario tiene su propio esquema. Esto es, un usuario DB_USU, será propietario de un esquema del mismo nombre.

En caso de que una vez conectado necesites establecer otro esquema diferente como el esquema por defecto, simplemente tendrás que ejecutar la consulta

```
ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA=nuevo_esquema
```

Solamente tendrías que ejecutar esto después de cada conexión.